# Project Euler #58: Primes along the diagonals of a square spiral

Tags: python, performance, programming-challenge, python-2.x, primes

I am working on [Project Euler Problem 58](https://projecteuler.net/problem=58):

> Starting with 1 and spiralling anticlockwise in the following way, a
>   square spiral with side length 7 is formed.
>
> ```
> 37 36 35 34 33 32 31
> 38 17 16 15 14 13 30
> 39 18  5  4  3 12 29
> 40 19  6  1  2 11 28
> 41 20  7  8  9 10 27
> 42 21 22 23 24 25 26
> 43 44 45 46 47 48 49
> ```
>
> It is interesting to note that the odd squares lie along the bottom
>   right diagonal, but what is more interesting is that 8 out of the 13
>   numbers lying along both diagonals are prime; that is, a ratio of 8/13
>   ≈ 62%.
>
> If one complete new layer is wrapped around the spiral above, a square
>   spiral with side length 9 will be formed. If this process is
>   continued, what is the side length of the square spiral for which the
>   ratio of primes along both diagonals first falls below 10%?

My code gives the correct answer, but it takes a very long time to do it, even while using Pypy, a JIT compiler.

I would like to know some good ways to increase my efficiency in this problem.

```
import random
def m_r(n):
    d = n - 1
    s = 0
    while d % 2 == 0:
        d >>= 1
        s += 1
    for repeat in range(20):
        a = 0
        while a == 0:
            a = random.randrange(n)
        if not miller_rabin_pass(a, s, d, n):
            return False
    return True

def miller_rabin_pass(a, s, d, n):
    a_to_power = pow(a, d, n)
    if a_to_power == 1:
        return True
    for i in range(s-1):
        if a_to_power == n - 1:
            return True
        a_to_power = (a_to_power * a_to_power) % n
    return a_to_power == n - 1

def eraSieve(n):
    sieve=[True]*(n+1)
    sieve[:2] = [False, False]
    sqrt = int(n**.5)+1
    for x in xrange(2, sqrt):
        if sieve[x]:
            sieve[2*x::x]=[False]*(n/x-1)
    return sieve

def diagonalNum(n): # n is the number of row
    increment = 2
    getDiaNum = 1
    limit = (n-1)/2
    sideLen = 1.0
    c = 0.0
    for i in xrange(1, limit + 1):
        count = 1
        while count <= 4:
            getDiaNum += increment
            if m_r(getDiaNum):
                c += 1
            count += 1
        increment += 2
        sideLen += 4
    return c / sideLen



for x in xrange(1, 100000):
    ratio = diagonalNum(x)
    print x
    if ratio < 0.10:
        break
print x
```

Comment: Each time you call `diagonalNum` from the main loop, it starts again from 1, repeating all the work done on the previous call (and the call before that, and so on). Why not maintain a running count?

Comment: @GarethRees What do you mean by running count?

Comment: @GarethRees That looks like it should be an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**A bit of math**

It is interesting to see that the corners of a square of size \$s\$ have values: \$s^2-3s+3\$, \$s^2-2s+2\$, \$s^2-s+1\$, \$s^2\$. (Also \$s^2\$ is not a prime ;-))

**My solution**

Not an actual review but if you find this useful:

```
def euler58(ratio=0.1):
    """Solution for problem 58."""
    # First analysis in euler28
    # Corners are s*s-3s+3, s*s-2s+2, s*s-s+1, s*s
    # s*s is likely not to be prime
    nb_prime = 0
    for s in itertools.count(3, 2):
        for i in range(1, 4):
            if is_prime(s * s - i * s + i):
                nb_prime += 1
        if nb_prime < ratio * (2 * s - 1):
            return s
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! I didn't realize those equations for the points of the square. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: What were you going to add? You never finished

Comment: @SomeGuy Going point! I really can't tell what I had in mind back then. I've added my solution in case it is useful to anyone

Comment: Nice. Also, n*n isn't just not likely to be prime, it's IMPOSSIBLE for n*n to be prime. 1 isn't a prime number.